# jquery date range picker not working on ajax callback

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

Here is the picker init

```
<div class="app">
<input type="text" id="pick" />
</div>


$('#pick').daterangepicker({
    timePickerIncrement: 30, format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
}, function(start, end) {
    start = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    end = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $.ajax({
        url: global_url+'statistics/analytics-ajax',
        data: 'start='+start+'&end='+end,
        dataType: 'html',
        method: 'post',
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        complete: function() {

        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.app').html(data);
            //$('#pick').daterangepicker();
        }

    })
});
```

On success call back I have a

div with class app will be replaced with

```
<input type="text" id="pick" />
```

But once the content is loaded through ajax daterangepicker not working so I added

```
$('#pick').daterangepicker();
```

and successfully I can see the daterangepicker but Ajax is not working. What is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

In case datepicker is part of ajax response data then include datepicker js script in that page itself.
or

Include this code before call to datepicker on success

`setTimeout(function(){alert('delay');}, 000);`

Comment: That is not my question

Comment: Is your datepicker part of ajax reponse data?